# Server Monitoring Software - designing database MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, monitoring

I want to create a monitoring script that will check my servers. Right now I'm stuck on a problem, I need to find out a way to get uptime percentage. Basically all data is stored in MySQL server, for me the easiest way to get uptime is to create a function that will add a new record to mysql server every minute with date, time, information is it online etc. but if I will use this method and I will have for example 1000 servers to monitor, I will end up with 518 400 000 records in MySQL server per year.

Another idea was to create one record per server with two rows online and offline, but without any date and time I'm not able to get uptime...

Any ideas how to design database for monitoring system ?

Comment: There are already existing tools for this like nagios, inciga, or zabbix

Comment: I don't want to use existing tools, I want to create my own monitoring script.

Comment: That's why I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL information_schema contains uptime information (expressed in seconds) for each server. I am not sure how accurate your figure has to be, but you could get this value at a set interval and compare it to the previous value. Depending on the interval, this could give you a good approximation.

```
SELECT Variable_Value FROM SESSION_STATUS S WHERE Variable_Name = 'UPTIME';
```

Also, the MySQL error log contains a date and time stamp when the server starts. Scrape this info periodically and add to your server table.

Comment: But to get this information I will need MySQL on each server ? I've got MySQL only on one server, and this server ping my other servers if the ping is successful then the script add "online" record to the database if ping fails then script will add "offline" record to the database

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to measure the uptime of database servers! Forget what I said above. I would not use a ping to determine uptime. A network issue on your database server might prevent the ping when in fact the other servers are fine. I would periodically scrape each servers boot log. On linux this is in /var/log/boot.log or /var/log/messages.  On Windows, event logs are in %SystemRoot%\system32\winevt\logs, but you need to use Event Viewer to read, or use MS Event Log API.